# Not able to post form in Adode CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem

I am a newbie in AdobeCQ5. I am facing some trouble in posting form. Here is my Structure -

```
/apps/<myproject>/components/mytestcomponent
```

mytestcomopnent.jsp  has following code -

```
<form id="myForm"  action="<%=resource.getPath()+".html" %>">
    <input type="text" id="t1" class="input-small" placeholder="Temprature F" />
    <input type="text" id="t2" class="input-small" placeholder="Temprature C" readonly/>
    <button type="button" id="cbtn" class="btn">Convert</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#cbtn').click(function ()  {        
            var URL = $("#myForm").attr("action");   
            alert(URL); 
            var t1=$("#t1").val();
            var t2=$("#t2").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                data:{'t1':t1},
                type:"post",
                success: function(data, status) {
                    $("#t2").val(data);
                },
                error: function( xhr, txtStat, errThrown ) {
                    alert("ajax  error! " + txtStat + ":::" + errThrown);
                }
            }); 
        }); 
    });    
</script>
```

This is giving my response code 200 (Success) but the output is not desired. My mycomponent.POST.jsp has following code -

```
<%
    // TODO add you code here
    String t1=request.getParameter("t1");
%>
<%= t1 %>
```

It gives the following output

```
  Content modified /content/imobile/en/jcr:content/social.html
  Status    
  200
  Message   
  OK
  Location     /content/imobile/en/_jcr_content/social.html
  Parent Location  /content/imobile/en/_jcr_content
  Path  
  /content/imobile/en/jcr:content/social.html
  Referer http://example.comt:4502/content/imobile/en.html
  ChangeLog 
 <pre></pre>
 Go Back
 Modified Resource
 Parent of Modified Resource
```

Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JSP file handling the POST method for your component should be named `POST.jsp` rather than `mycomponent.POST.jsp`.

Please notice that if you intercept all POST requests to your component, you won't be able to edit it on the author instance using a dialog (as the dialog simply POSTs data to the component URL). To avoid it, consider using a custom selector (like `form`). Your form should look be declared like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="${resource.path}.form.html">
```

and the script handling POST request should be called `form.POST.jsp`.

The second important thing is that you should use Java classes rather than JSP files to store business logic. In this case it means that the `form.POST.jsp` script can be replaced with a [Sling servlet](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) declared as follows:

```
@SlingServlet(
    resourceTypes="myproject/components/mytestcomponent",
    methods="POST",
    selectors="form")
```

Comment: Thanks @TomekRękawek ! The extra info-bit about using selectors to differentiate POST request made through a form and through the dialog is a god-send